# Flag review queue fades to much after reviewing

Tags: bug, meta, 10k-tools

#### The bug

[image: hover bug]

When moving your mouse from an already reviewed flag, it'll fade. However, when opening the close dialog, not only the question fades, but also 3 of the 5 close vote reasons.

#### The context

I can only reproduce this on MSO, the bug doesn't appear on SO.

#### Reproduce

1. Pick a flag on a question in the review queue on MSO
2. Review the flag
3. Open the "close" dialog
4. Hover with the mouse outside the flag queue

Comment: @closevoters: [**It's fine if users post bug reports, requests for support or feature requests here on MSO, there's no need to close them as off-topic. Please, don't do that, it's off-putting and rude.**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them)

Comment: Besides what @Matt says, it only occurs on MSO, so it doesn't really apply to the whole community